# Pandas - Append data to specific columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to append data from a list to a specific column. 
I have 4 lists:

```
orderNumber = ['123456789']
countryOfOrigin = ['United Kingdom']
sizeList = ['2', '4']
quantityList = ['10', '12']
```

I also have a CSV file with following headers:

```
OrderNumber   COO   Size   QTY
```

I need these lists appended to this CSV in their correct columns. And if list only has one item in the data is simply dublicated to fill all rows

```
OrderNumber        COO         Size   QTY
123456789     United Kingdom    2     10
123456789     United Kingdom    4     20
```

This is what I tried. But all it does it adds everything one under another in the same column

```
orderNumber = ['123456789']
countryOfOrigin = ['United Kingdom']
sizeList = ['2', '4']
quantityList = ['10', '12']

header = ["OrderNumber", "COO", "Size", "QTY"]
order = pd.DataFrame(orderNumber)
order.to_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pandas-Example2.csv', mode='a', index=False)
size = pd.DataFrame(sizeList, columns=["Size"])
size.to_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Pandas-Example2.csv', mode='a', index=False)
```

Any idea how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible use instead one element lists only scalars, create dictionary of scalars/lists and pass to `DataFrame` constructor - all lists has to be with same lengths:

```
orderNumber = '123456789'
countryOfOrigin = 'United Kingdom'
sizeList = ['2', '4']
quantityList = ['10', '12']

d = {"OrderNumber": orderNumber, "COO":countryOfOrigin, "Size":sizeList, "QTY":quantityList}
order = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (order)
  OrderNumber             COO Size QTY
0   123456789  United Kingdom    2  10
1   123456789  United Kingdom    4  12
```

If inputs are always lists you can use some preprocessing:

```
orderNumber = ['123456789']
countryOfOrigin = ['United Kingdom']
sizeList = ['2', '4']
quantityList = ['10', '12']

vals = [orderNumber, countryOfOrigin, sizeList, quantityList]
header = ["OrderNumber", "COO", "Size", "QTY"]

d = {a: b[0] if len(b) == 1 else b for a, b in zip(header, vals)}
order = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (order)
  OrderNumber             COO Size QTY
0   123456789  United Kingdom    2  10
1   123456789  United Kingdom    4  12
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. - The inputs are always lists. This is a part of a larger program that takes about 10 inputs from from the users and stores them all in the list. 8 of those lists will only have one item in them and the remaining two will have multiple (but always the same amount). So I needed some way to copy the singular items list down as many times as many rows were created by the other two lists. Could you tell me why would I want to use 'Preprocessing'?

Comment: @babis95 - Just edited answer for more general solution, dictionary is generated by input lists. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Both of these solutions work perfectly. I'm not sure what I'm looking at with the second option especially `d = {a: b[0] if len(b) == 1 else b for a, b in zip(header, vals)}` this line. Would you mind briefly explaining it?

Comment: @babis95 - sure, it convert one eleemnt lists to scalars. so `['123456789']` change to `'123456789'`.  Give list and test if length is 1, then select first value so returned `'123456789'`, else not touch - so if length is more like 1 it return same value - so for `['10', '12']` return `['10', '12']`